# How to animate an arc from the middle in both directions

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have been able to make an arc that animates from one end to another using the following coroutine:

```
IEnumerator AnimateArc(float duration)
{
float waitDur = duration / pts;

for (int i = 0; i <= pts; i++)
{

    float x = center.x + radius * Mathf.Cos(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    float y = center.y + radius * Mathf.Sin(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    arcLineRend.positionCount = i + 1;

    arcLineRend.SetPosition(i, new Vector2(x, y));

    ang += (float)totalAngle / pts;

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitDur);

}
}
```

How can I animate this arc from the middle in both directions

1. at a constant speed
2. with an ease (animates slightly faster around the halfway (of the half) and slows down towards the end)

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the two-directions part you will probably need to use two line renderers and change the coordinates for the second direction to `center.x - radius * Mathf.Cos((180f-ang) * Mathf.Deg2Rad)` and for y respectively.

Constant speed is what you have right now, for the other one, have a search for `slerp (spherical interpolation`. Use some bool to switch between those two.

Also, just to give it a try for myself I've put in you code in a project and I had to change a few things for it to work properly:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class LineCalculator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float pts = 15f;
    public Vector2 center = new Vector2(0, 0);
    public float radius = 5f;
    public float totalAngle = 180f;

    LineRenderer lR;

    private void Awake()
    {
        lR = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(AnimateArc(5f));
    }

    IEnumerator AnimateArc(float duration)
    {
        float waitDur = duration / pts;
        WaitForSeconds sleep = new WaitForSeconds(waitDur);   // This is just for saving a tiny bit of performance

        float ang = 0f;
        float step = totalAngle / (pts-1);   // -1 because I ended up with one point to much (pts seems to not include the starting point)

        for (int i = 0; i < pts; i++)  // Only go to i < pts
        {
            float x = center.x + radius * Mathf.Cos(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
            float y = center.y + radius * Mathf.Sin(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);

            lR.positionCount = i + 1;

            lR.SetPosition(i, new Vector2(x, y));

            ang += step;

            yield return sleep;
        }
    }
}
```